# Sencha Touch 2: Call controller function from within Ext.Msg.confirm

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm just getting started with Sencha Touch 2 and I have never worked with Sencha Touch 1.x before. I've just finished this tutorial (which is the best starter tutorial I have found so far) http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/ and now I want to go ahead and extend this Notes App.

I have a controller and 2 views, a list view and an edit view. In the edit view I want to be able to delete the current record. The delete function is in the controller. After tapping the delete button, I want to show a confirmation dialog ("Are you sure you want to delete...?"). After the user presses yes, the delete function should be called.

Now my problem is: How do I call the controllers delete function from within Ext.Msg.confirm?

Here are the relevant snippets of my code. Please let me know if something important is missing.

Please see the "onDeleteNoteCommand" function. "this.someFunction" obviously doesn't work since "this" is a DOMWindow.

```
Ext.define('TestApp2.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
        noteEditorView: 'noteeditorview'
    },
    control: {
        noteEditorView: {
            deleteNoteCommand: 'onDeleteNoteCommand',
        }
    }
},

onDeleteNoteCommand: function() {
    console.log('onDeleteNoteCommand');

    var noteEditor = this.getNoteEditorView();
    var currentNote = noteEditor.getRecord();

    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Delete note?",
        "Do you reall want to delete the note <i>"+currentNote.data.title+"</i>?",
        function(buttonId) {
            if(buttonId === 'yes') {
                            //controller functions!! how to call them?
                this.deleteNote(currentNote);                   
                this.activateNotesList();
            }
        }
    );
},

deleteNote: function(record) {
    var notesStore = Ext.getStore('Notes');
    notesStore.remove(record);
    notesStore.sync();
},

activateNotesList: function() {
    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(this.getNotesListView(), this.slideRightTransition);
},

slideLeftTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' },
slideRightTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' },

launch: function() {
    this.callParent();
    Ext.getStore('Notes').load();
    console.log('launch main controller');
},
init: function() {
    this.callParent();
    console.log('init main controller');
}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enter callback function of Ext.Msg the scope changes from controller scope to global  scope  (window), so you must set up it as parameter of confirm method:

```
  Ext.Msg.confirm(
      "Delete note?",
      "Do you reall want to delete the note <i>"+currentNote.data.title+"</i>?",
      function(buttonId) {
        if(buttonId === 'yes') {
          this.deleteNote(currentNote);                   
          this.activateNotesList();
        }
      }, 
      this // scope of the controller 
    );
```

For more info please check sencha docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox-method-confirm

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but I think you misunderstood. The onDeleteNoteCommand event is getting called fine. Within "onDeleteNoteCommand" I'm showing a confirmation box. There I want to call another controller function. Hope this is clear.

Comment: You only have to add "this" as the fourth parameter of the confirm method :)

Comment: Ohh, thank you! :-) So simple, yet I wasn't able to figure it out, even with the docs here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-1.1.1/docs/output/Ext.MessageBox.html

Now I see I should have looked at the Public methods of Ext.MessageBox. There is the scope!